# Boy carves Initials onto turtle shell; years later, turtle is gigantic

Tags: identify-this-movie

Years ago (late 80’s to early 90’s), we watched a movie in which a seaside town is terrorized by a sea-monster which turns out to be a giant turtle. At the very end of the movie, the turtle sinks into the ocean and we see its shell with the initials (with the typical ‘+’ and heart, I think) that the boy and girl carved onto it when they were young.

I tried [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=giant%20turtle%20shell%20engraved%20initials%20movie), but the only thing I could find were some news articles about a real-life incident (from May 2012) where a turtle is found 47 years after a boy carved his initials in its shell. Obviously the movie predates the real-life incident (strange that I thought of the movie only a few weeks after the news broke).

Does anyone know what the movie was?

Comment: was this an american film?  how did you see it?

Comment: The Wikipedia page says it is an American/Japanese production. I saw it on television in Canada.

Comment: I have been trying to find this movie myself. I think it's also like a love story type movie.

Comment: @lgoss, yes, the boy and girl were friends when they were little and were reunited and fell in love years later when they were older.

Comment: It's not the Japanese/American one. I also remember the turtle rescuing the 2 as adults later in the movie. I think their ship sank or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be this movie?

The [Bermuda Depths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bermuda_Depths). The plot element on the page looks a more closer match.

> Magnus dreams of his childhood, playing on the same beach. He finds a
>   turtle egg in the sand, and calls to his friend Jennie to have a look.
>   As they watch, the egg hatches. A few years later, Magnus and Jennie
>   play with the rather large turtle. Magnus takes a shell and carves
>   "J+M" inside a heart on the turtle's shell, while Jennie finishes
>   making a coral necklace, which she places around Magnus's neck.

Comment: It very well might be. A few things (e.g. Japanese/American movie, Carl Weathers) don’t quite fit, but the rest fits quite well, especially the end (even the initials ‘J+M’ seems familiar). I can’t find any [useful pictures](http://images.google.com/images?q=bermuda+depths&sout=1), but I think it’s safe to assume that this is it.

Comment: @Synetech - There's some footage on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0Kg8ZYo19w#t=00m31s), maybe that will jog your memory.

Comment: It's ALL over YouTube in snippets.